# Cordova / PhoneGap - bring the app from background to foreground programmatically

Tags: cordova

Is it possible to bring the Cordova / PhoneGapp application to the programmatically? My use case is similar to incoming call like Viber. Is there any solutions from Cordova or plugins to address this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32376247/phonegap-bring-from-background-to-foreground/54786108#54786108

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution!

I installed the necessary plugin and searched for the right information.

See this on this question: [Phonegap - Bring from background to foreground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32376247/phonegap-bring-from-background-to-foreground/32378155#32378155)