# Phonegap - Bring from background to foreground

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm developing my team along with an application that must run in the background when an event called by sockets should put the application in the foreground .

The application must come to foreground similar to viber or whatsapp call. I stopped at this point. My application can now call an audio and vibrate, but I have to draw the screen to the foreground.

I'm using version 5.1.1 phonegap.

I am this plugin: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode

Could someone give me a hand? Very grateful this already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a way! Using the "toForeground" plugin. https://github.com/caioladislau/cordova-toforeground

```
      cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();

      cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.onactivate = function() {
        setTimeout(function(){ 
          toForeground("MainActivity", "com.me.myapp", function() {
            navigator.notification.vibrate(1000);
          }, function(){
            navigator.notification.vibrate(5000);
          }); 
        }, 4000);
      };
```

Note where it is called in:

```
toForeground(mainClassName, packageName, successFunction, errorFunction);
```

To find the "mainClassName" and "packageName" I searched: platforms/android/src/com/me/myapp/MainActivity.java, and I found:

```
package com.me.myapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        loadUrl(launchUrl);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is only for Android.

Comment: PushKit is the solution for iOS

Answer (score 1):

I have used this plugin instead of developing one for my own, its a forked repo 
https://github.com/suhail339/cordova-bring-to-front

> Keep in mind to install from Cordova CLI, visual studio plugin
>   installer might create problem.