# Bringing a PhoneGap app to the foreground

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, background-process

I'm writing an app with a reminder component in it. Once the user enters the time to be reminded by, the app is sent to the background. (I'm currently using a plugin to keep the app active in the background (https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode)).

The program seems to run in the background, but, when it's time to set off the alarm, it does so quietly (and in the background). I would like the "Snooze"/"Dismiss" dialog it generates to be presented to the user in the foreground.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to post a UILocalNotification on iOS.

Comment: OK, but I was wondering whether there is an HTML5/JS solution to the issue (that's what I'm developing in).

Comment: Once an app is in the background on iOS (and by the way with that plugin you won't get App Store approval) all you can do is post a notification - I don't use Cordova but I presume someone will have written a plugin to do that.

Comment: That's interesting. I am doing a cordova app only for android and the behaviour is the opposite. I am trying to keep the app in the background but it comes to the foreground once the alarm is triggered. What are you using to schedule/trigger alarms?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32376247/phonegap-bring-from-background-to-foreground/54786108#54786108

Answer (score 0):

The plugin looks to be a custom `Service` so, from the source, you could edit the `KeepAliveTask.run()` method with an event listener that listens for the alarm (Broadcast Receiver?).

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/caioladislau/cordova-toforeground plugin like this:

```
  cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();

  cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.onactivate = function() {
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      toForeground("MainActivity", "com.package.name", function() {
        console.log("foreground")
      }, function(){
        console.log("background still")
      }); 
    }, 4000);
  };
```

Comment: it's only for Android