# Bring cordova application to foreground when push arrives

Tags: java, android, cordova

I have app up and running. Push notifications are working ok. I need that when push arrives, bring app to foreground, on Android. So, what I found is this piece of code:

```
Intent toLaunch = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

toLaunch.setAction("android.intent.action.MAIN");
toLaunch.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
```

Taken from this question:
[Bring application to front after user clicks on home button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074980/bring-application-to-front-after-user-clicks-on-home-button)

I am trying to put this code in GCMIntentService.java from cordova push plugin. No matter where I put it, on compile i always get this error:

```
/appdir/android/src/com/plugin/gcm/GCMIntentService.java:94: error: cannot find symbol
Intent toLaunch = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                                                      ^
symbol:   class MainActivity
location: class GCMIntentService
```

Any ideas how to access this "MainActivity.class" from cordova plugin .java file?

Comment: Do you have MainActivity is not application.. If its present import this. Otherwise give the activity name which you want to open on push notification

Comment: Can you share your final solution it might help some people?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32376247/phonegap-bring-from-background-to-foreground/54786108#54786108

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The java compiler is telling you that it doesn't know what `MainActivity.class` is while compiling `GCMIntentService.java`. You must import `MainActivity` class from the package where it is defined e.g. if the package is called `cordovaExample` then at the top of `GCMIntentService.java` put

```
import cordovaExample.MainActivity;
```

and the class must be declared public

```
package cordova;

public class MainActivity {
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did, Changes on GMCIntentService.java file which worked great for me.

```
import com.package.app.*;


@Override
        protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onMessage - context: " + context);

    // Extract the payload from the message
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null)
    {
        // if we are in the foreground, just surface the payload, else post it to the statusbar
        if (PushPlugin.isInForeground()) {
            extras.putBoolean("foreground", true);
            PushPlugin.sendExtras(extras);
        }
        else {
            extras.putBoolean("foreground", false);

            Log.d(TAG, "force launch event");
            Intent wintent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            wintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(wintent);

            // Send a notification if there is a message
            if (extras.getString("message") != null && extras.getString("message").length() != 0) {
                createNotification(context, extras);
                PushPlugin.sendExtras(extras);
            }
        }
    }
}
```